# Can't click button with selenium (type=button)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button

I got the problem with click button in website:

Website:
https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/energy/refined-products/gasoil-01-rotterdam-barges-swap.quotes.html

Program opens website but couldn't click on button to load all data

I find in httml code a

```
<button type="button" class=" primary load-all btn btn-"><span class="text">Load All</span></button>
```

I'd like to click “LOAD ALL” on the button of webside but I get error.

Like this:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
> selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

My code is :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)
......
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path,options=options)
driver.get(website)
all_matches_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,value=" primary load-all btn btn-")
all_matches_button.click()
```

Finally I need to download all data in table (Month and PRIORSETTLE)

Thanks A lot

Comment: Provided link gives "Sorry...The page you are looking for cannot be found."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not able to locate the element is because the `class` value has space between the words(`" primary load-all btn btn-"`). In this instance `By.CLASS_NAME` will not work. You need to try using some other locator strategy like XPath or CSS Selector.

**Try the below code:**

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Load All')]")`

**OR Try by inducing waits like below:** (using `presence_of_element_located`)

```
all_matches_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Load All')]")))
```

**OR:** (using `element_to_be_clickable`)

```
all_matches_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Load All')]")))
```

**UPDATE:**

This element Load All is actually within `span` tag and not `button` tag.

Try this XPath:

`//span[contains(text(),'Load All')]`

See the image below your reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for yours answer but still doesn't work.
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),'Load All')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.99)

Comment: Try by inducing waits. Check the updated answer.

Comment: all the time ... 

    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I feel depressed... its still the same.. 
Mayby reasson is
somewhere else ? For example if I Used "#all_matches_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[type=button]")" website open in "serach button" .... I have to find solution is very important for me.. thanks you a lot for help me

Answer (score 0):

Your locator is wrong

You should use ***Xpath***

```
all_matches_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Load All')]")
all_matches_button.click()
```

***OR CSS Selector***

```
all_matches_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"primary.load-all.btn.btn-")
all_matches_button.click()
```

Comment: thanks, but still does't work:
Response
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"primary.load-all.btn.btn-"}
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.99)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
 (No symbol) [0x008CF243]
 (No symbol) [0x00857FD1]
 (No symbol) [0x0074D04D]
 (No symbol) [0x0077C0B0]
 .......
 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B77B8E+238]

Comment: I am not able to access the web add the HTML source for the element - OR try to scroll to the element and click OR use ActionChain to move to the element and click.

Comment: I put corrected link in post few minutes ago